# postGre SQL requesting type cast when datatypes match?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I've been trying this query here:

```
    SELECT
     account.customer_client_code,
     account.client_account_number,
     account.first_name,
     account.last_name,
     debt_trans.trans_date,
     debt_trans.debt_id,
     debt_trans.debt_trans_id,
     debt_trans.receiver,
     debt_trans.type_name,
     debt_trans.client_id,
     debt_trans.amount

    FROM
     debt_trans 

    INNER JOIN
     account 

    ON
     account.client_id= debt_trans.client_id

      /* Both fields here are of int8 datatype */

    WHERE
     debt_trans.customer_id = 'CMC' 
     and
     account.customer_client_code like ('UBC2903','UBCO') 
     and 
     debt_trans.type_name='Credit Card'
     and
     debt_trans.operator = 'RECEIVED'

 /*All of these fields here are of varchar datatype */
```

But I've checked and double checked all the datatypes and there shouldn't be any type casting. The error message I get is the following:

**"ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying ~~ record Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. Position: 492"**

Any hints on what's the problem?

Comment: Can you determine which character is at position 492?

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pertaining to this line:

```
account.customer_client_code like ('UBC2903','UBCO')
```

If you are trying to see if `account.customer_client_code` is one of `'UBC2903'` or `'UBCO'`, then you should use the `IN` operator:

```
account.customer_client_code IN ('UBC2903','UBCO')
```